# Изменение цвета фона четных ячеек таблицы

Tags: jquery

Только начала изучать jQuery, первая программа из книжки, и она не работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .stripped {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .table {
              border: 1px solid black; 
              border-collapse: collapse;
             }
            .table tr {
              border: 1px solid black;

            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("table tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("stripped");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table">
            <tr><td>текст 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>текст 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>текст 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>текст 4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>текст 5</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Что в коде неправильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы, случайно, не забыли подключить библиотеку `jquery`? Проверьте, пожалуйста. Так как в примере она не подключается. И в этом случае результат прогнозированный ;)

UPD.

```
чего сейчас не хватает?
```

А теперь вы вызываете функцию $("table tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("stripped"); до того, как у вас сформировался DOM документа. То есть вы вызываете раньше, чем таблица появилась на странице и яваскрипт ничего не находит.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // вызывается после подготовки DOM страницы
  $("table tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("stripped");
})
```

Comment: О, большое  спасибо, забыла, что это не просто javascript, а нужна библиотека

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Для этого мы здесь :)

Comment: Хм, добавила в хэд строку <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
вроде этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы jquery работала, но она таки не работает.
чего сейчас не хватает?

Comment: Добавил в ответ. Вам надо или воспользоваться $(document).ready(function(){...}) или добавлять яваскрипт в конце страницы (второе менее предпочтительно).

Comment: УРРРРА!!! Оно заработало!!!

Comment: ждём вопроса по второму скрипту из книги

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокласс :nth-child доступен в обычном CSS

Comment: Верно, но тут пытаются научиться использованию jquery и делать выборки разного рода (как например все четные строки таблицы) неплохое начало. Даже указали, что это первый урок из книги.

Comment: я знаю, что псевдокласс :nth-child доступен в css, но я хочу применить jQuery.